# VB6 Missing DLL error when passing Excel object to function on some machines but works if not passed. why?

Tags: excel, object, dll, vb6

I can't figure out why some users (but not all) are seeing errors if I pass Excel to another function or sub with VB6.

This fails for some but not all. They get missing DLL or interface not registered error.

```
sub test()
Dim xl As Object, xlwbook As Object, xlsheet As Object
Set xl = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set xlwbook = xl.Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
xlwbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "REPORT"
Set xlsheet = xlwbook.Sheets("REPORT") 

Call formatlogo(xlsheet)
End Sub

function formatlogo(xlsheet As Worksheet)
xlsheet.Cells(1, 1).Characters(1, 1).Font.Name = "Webdings"
end function
```

This works for everyone.

```
sub test()
Dim xl As Object, xlwbook As Object, xlsheet As Object
Set xl = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set xlwbook = xl.Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
xlwbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "REPORT"
Set xlsheet = xlwbook.Sheets("REPORT") 

xlsheet.Cells(1, 1).Characters(1, 1).Font.Name = "Webdings"
End Sub
```

Why can't I pass an Excel object without dll errors for some folks?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting?

Comment: Error 48 Error in loading DLL

Comment: Possibly an early-binding-to-runtime com version issue.  `... As Worksheet` on the working systems (including your dev system) is the dll version on your dev system.  On the not working systems, that's a different dll installed there (different Excel versions, maybe?). Since you're late binding instantiating the Excel objects anyway, try changing the function to `Function formatlogo(xlsheet As Object)`